# int * and HANDLE * equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have this line of codes in C++

```
WD_OpenDevice(PCSTR szDevPath, HANDLE *phDevice, HANDLE ahChannels[], int *pnChannelNum, int iVideoStandard = WD_VID_STD_PAL, PCSTR szUser = NULL, PCSTR szPswd = NULL);
```

And call it

```
WD_OpenDevice("xxxxxxxx", &m_hDev, m_ahChannels, &m_nChannelNum);
```

What's is the equivalent of int * and HANDLE * in C# ?

I have converted it to this code in C# using DllImport. But it's not work.

```
[DllImport("WD_SDK.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int WD_OpenDevice(string szDevPath, IntPtr phDevice, IntPtr[] ahChannels, int pnChannelNum, int iVideoStandard = 1, string szUser = null, string szPswd = null);
```

I call it

```
 IntPtr[] m_ahChannels = new IntPtr[4];
            int m_nChannelNum = 0;
            IntPtr m_hDev = new IntPtr();
            a = WD_OpenDevice("wdvr://localhost/qqdvr", m_hDev, m_ahChannels, m_nChannelNum);
```

Error raised:

[image]

Comment: When it "did not work" can you explain how it did not work, did you get error messages, unexpected behavior, something else? If you got any error messages please copy and paste the full test of the error as a edit to your question.

Comment: You can use int* in C# but you need to add the `unsafe` keyword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WD_OpenDevice(PCSTR szDevPath,
              HANDLE *phDevice,
              HANDLE ahChannels[],
              int *pnChannelNum,
              int iVideoStandard = WD_VID_STD_PAL,
              PCSTR szUser = NULL,
              PCSTR szPswd = NULL);
```

is

```
[DllImport("WD_SDK.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern int WD_OpenDevice(string szDevPath,
                                ref IntPtr phDevice,
                                IntPtr[] ahChannels,
                                ref int pnChannelNum,
                                int iVideoStandard = 1,
                                string szUser = null,
                                string szPswd = null);
```

Depending on what the function does, you might want to replace `ref` with `out`.